How can I compile zookeeper c client 3.8.4?
I want to compile c client for zookeeper, I cloned the codes and checkout it to tag 3.8.4. Then I did as follows:
1 install libcppunit-dev
2 enter zookeeper-jute and execute command mvn compile, got success
3 enter to the top dir zookeeper to execute ant compile_jute, but got Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
4 enter to zookeeper/zookeeper-client/zookeeper-client-c, execute autoreconf -if, got
configure.ac:38: error: Missing AM_PATH_CPPUNIT or PKG_CHECK_MODULES m4 macro.
acinclude.m4:317: CHECK_CPPUNIT is expanded from...
configure.ac:38: the top level
autom4te: error: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: /usr/bin/autom4te failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: error: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
error: Missing AM_PATH_CPPUNIT or PKG_CHECK_MODULES m4 macro.

But I have installed libcppunit-dev, what did I do wrong??
